# Fragment is under the Buttons of the MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I 'm new in Android Programming an i have a problem:
I have a "Main Page" where are some Buttons. If I replace the RelativeLayout with my Fragment are the Buttons over the List of the Fragment. How can I make the Buttons invisible after i started my Fragment?
[Here is a Screenshot. All yellow marked are from the MainActivity and the list behind them is from the fragment. [LINK]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8swF5.png)

**The important Code:**

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_functions) {
        startFragment(FunctionsFragment.newInstance(1), "TagFunctions");
        Log.d("SMSAT", "nav_functions pressed");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_macro) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_platzhalter) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void startFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag){


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment, tag).commit();

    Log.d("SMSAT", "startFragment() ausgeführt");

}

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="de.mika.smsantitheft.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
android:id="@+id/main_relative_layout">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/home_sms_commands"
    android:id="@+id/textViewSmsBefehleStatus"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

  <ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToggleButton"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:textOn="@string/aktivated"
    android:textOff="@string/deaktivated"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSmsBefehleStatus"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp" />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/menu_functions"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/menu_macros"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/menu_settings"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/menu_contact"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/menu_recommend"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"></FrameLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the buttons into a layout. change the entire layout visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the buttons invisible in startFragment?

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_location);
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Ok I try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use add method other than replacing it.

If that doesn't help, try to set your appliaction's theme to android:Theme.Material.Light.

If that does not help, set your new fragment's background to white on XML. That will make you feel like another sheet on your notebook.